# Calling two functions using "and"

Tags: python

Is it pythonic to call one function after the other? I have two functions, and one depends of the result of the other:

```
function1() # if something goes wrong, will raise a error, if not, will return None
function2()
```

And I was thinking about using:

```
function1() is None and function2()
```

Is this pythonic?

Comment: Does it depend on the result? You don't return and pass anything, is there a side effect? If so, that's not very pythonic in itself.

Comment: why dont you call `function2` inside of `function1`?

Comment: I'm using a module that i need first execute a query (function1), then i call the fetchone (function2) to collect the result of the query (function1). So, the second function depends on the result of the first function, but the result is inside of the module, the first function won't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't think of the return value of `None` as indicating success, but rather the *absence* of an exception. Use a `try` statement to make it explicit that you are aware of the possibility of an exception, but are intentionally letting it pass up the call chain should one be raised:

```
try:
    function1()
else:
    function2()
```

If you want, you can be explicit:

```
try:
    function1()
except Exception:
    raise
else:
    function2()
```

Comment: The problem is that i'm creating a module on top of this other module, so was think to let the module users  decide how to handle the exceptions @chepner

Comment: Then you don't need to do *anything* special. Just call the two functions sequentially; you'll only reach the second call if the first one doesn't raise an uncaught exception. The return value really isn't meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to use a `try....except` test instead of two separate functions

```
MyFunction()
try:
    <your first action goes here>
except:
    <what you want to happen if an error occurs go here>
```

You might need to use two `except` statements, one for a `None` return and one for any others. There is plenty of useful information in the documentation: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions